# `default_scope order('created_at DESC')` works, but `Model.order('created_at DESC')` doesn't work with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I'm using `kaminari` for pagination in rails.

if I set `default_scope order("created_at DESC")` in model, it works as expected.

But when I write in controller like this, the `DESC` is ignored and pages are ordered by ascendent. (In this case I don't write `default_scope` in model.)

```
  def index
    @words = Word.order("created_at DESC").page params[:page]
  end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: doesn't look like there's anything wrong. Might be something in your view?

Comment: I think, there is nothing special in view. Like `@words.each do |word|` and so on.

Comment: so running Word.all gives you the proper default scope, but running what you typed does not? Anyway it should be okay to just do Word.page(params[:page]) since the default scope is implemented? if you really can't just perform a .reverse to get things working for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it applies both orders if want to ignore previous scope then use this:

```
@words = Word.unscoped.order("created_at DESC").page params[:page]
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated more clearly. When I write in controller, I don't write in model file.

Comment: There is no issue regarding code location default scope applies everywhere